# Pandas: fill NaNs based on group text values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in pandas:

```
  ID  value
0  A  textA
1  A  textA
2  A   None
3  B   None
4  B  textB
5  C   None
```

I would like to replace `None` values with other value from the same column by group. The problem is that I have `string` type data in the value column. There can be also situation when there is no other value like in case of `ID = C`, then the value of course should left `None`.

This is what I need:

```
  ID  value
0  A  textA
1  A  textA
2  A  textA
3  B  textB
4  B  textB
5  C   None
```

Is this possible assuming that all other than `None` values are the same? What in the situation when there will be different values for one group?

Comment: If assuming all values are the same within groups: `df['value'] = df.gropuby('ID')['value'].transform('first')`. Else you can do, e.g `ffill` instead of `'first'`.